# Message posted gets truncated in listview. How can I wrap text instead of truncating

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

Following is my discussion activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bg_login"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/msgview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"></ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Send" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the code for items in the list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/view">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messages_list_element_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:text="askdjnqkjwnkjqnwe"
    android:padding="5dp"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="70"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messages_list_element_textview_header"
        style="@style/category_list_textview"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/bg_login"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="ajksndjnqwjndqkjnw"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messages_list_element_textview_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/messages_list_element_textview_header"
        android:textColor="@color/bg_login"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="asdadsad"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The messages that appear on the phone seems to be truncated. I am displaying the message under "messages_list_element_textview_header" element of the layout and it seems to display a limited number of characters in is a single line with dots towards the end(truncated)

I would like to display all the text being entered by the user. Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your TextView include the fields maxLines:

`android:maxLines="x"`

where x is the max number of lines you want.

You can also do this programatically with the method `TextView#setMaxLines(int)`